# ¿Cómo puedo obtener una pagina totalmente cargada con requests o urllib?

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup, scraping

Estoy empezando en esto del web scraping y estoy intentando descargar todas las imágenes de un post de imgur, hay más de 1500 pero sólo me descarga las primeras 15, eso es porque la página va cargando de 15 imágenes.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el `request.get(url).content` me de la página totalmente cargada o con alguna otra librería?

---

El código de mi scraper es el siguiente:

Librerías y funciones útiles.

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from os import listdir as ls
from random import randint as rand

abc = "abcdefghijklmjopqrstuvwxyz"
abc = abc + abc.upper() + "1234567890_"

def get_ext(url):
    return url[-4:]

def fix_rel(url, prot="http"):
    if url[:len(prot)] == prot:
        return url
    else:
        if url[:2] == "//":
            return prot + ":" + url
        else:
            return prot + ":/" + url

def random_string(leng=5):
    gen = str()
    for el in range(0,leng):
        gen = gen + abc[rand(0, len(abc)-1)]
    return gen

def add(q):
    try:
        return str(int(q) + 1)
    except:
        return str(q) + random_string(8)

def setfilename(dire, name="1", ext=".txt"):
    if name + ext in ls(dire):
        return setfilename(dire, add(name), ext)
    else:
        return name + ext

def down(url, dest, filename="download", ext=".txt"):
    f = open(dest + setfilename(dest, filename, ext),"w")
    f.write(r.get(url).content)
    f.close()
```

El web scraping

```py
url = "http://m.imgur.com/a/46UVO"
# url = "http://m.imgur.com/gallery/hW9it"
dest = "/sdcard/images/mlpedits/"
print "Descargando html..."
sopa = bs(ul.urlopen(url).read(), "html.parser")
i = 0
ok = 0
print "Descargando imagenes..."
imagenes = sopa.findAll("img")
c = len(imagenes)
for el in imagenes:
    i += 1
    try:
        down(basic.fix_rel(el["src"]), dest, "a", basic.get_ext(el["src"]))
        print str(i) + "/" + str(c) + " -> " + el["src"]
        ok += 1
    except:
        print str(i) + "/" + str(c) + " x " + el["src"]

print "\n\n", str(ok) + "/" + str(i) + " descargados"
```

Comment: Estaria bien que pusieras codigo, un link de la página, etc . Hay muchas formas de hacer esto pero importa mucho la estructura de la pagina, (herramientas como el inspector web de Firefox son de mucha ayuda a para ver el html de la pagina en cuestión). Es importante saber como carga las imagenes restantes, haciendo click en un botón para cargar las siguientes, con scroll infinito, etc Para scroll infinito puede ayudarte la libreria selenium (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DFNnCezy

Comment: imgur te debe estar dando un resultado paginado tienes que buscar como utilizar scrapy con paginación

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Para páginas dinámicas se usa Selenium WebDriver a la hora de scrapear. BeautifulSoup y requests solo sirven para webs estáticas, o sea, las que no tienen nada adicional que cargar.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300387)